# Zigfu/OpenNI, The device is not connected

Tags: kinect, openni

I'm trying to work with the [Zigfu](http://zigfu.com/) API but I am having some issues.  I have tried installing on both Windows 7 and Mac OSX 10.7.2 but to no avail.  The message I recieve in Windows 7:

```
One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Device: PrimeSense/SensorKinect/5.1.0.25: The device is not connected!
Device: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.25: The device is not connected!
Device: PrimeSense/SensorKinect/5.1.0.25: The device is not connected!
Device: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.25: The device is not connected!

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't have the error meesage I receive in OSX but something about the resource is unavailable (I'll post an update when I get back on that machine) but what is the issue here?

Ultimately I am trying to work with the Unity binding Zigfu has made, any recommendations getting started there would be greatly appreciated too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error is reported by OpenNI and means there is no communication with the sensor. You should:

1. Make sure your depth sensor is plugged in (both to your computer USB port and external power supply, assuming you're using Kinect)
2. Try plugging your sensor into a different USB port
3. Make sure Microsoft Kinect SDK isn't installed (Windows only, assuming you're using the Kinect).

You can also try installing Microsoft Kinect SDK and running the samples there just to make sure the sensor is working.

Feel free to email us at info@zigfu.com to get into our private beta of the new Zigfu bindings for Unity3d (incl. webplayer), HTML/JS, and Flash.

Hope that helps,
Shlomo